# Babel ESLint parser difficulties

Tags: javascript, babeljs, eslint, babel-eslint

Hi I am quite new to ESLint and when I was gaining some headway I encountered issues with the assert when [importing a JSON file. I added the babel ESLint parser but on setting everything up I noticed all of my rules are no longer being read, I spent a good amount of time trying to figure out a solution but with no luck, could someone please assist me with this? This my .eslintrc.json file:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true,
        "mocha": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:import/errors",
        "plugin:import/warnings"
    ],
    "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",

    "parserOptions": {
        "requireConfigFile": false,
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "sourceType": "module",
        "babelOptions": {
                "plugins": [
                  "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-assertions"
                ]
    },

    "rules": {

        "@babel/indent": ["error", 4],

        "linebreak-style": ["error", "windows"],

        "quotes": ["error", "single"],

        "semi": ["error", "always"],

        "prefer-template": ["error"], 

        "block-spacing": ["error", 
            "always"
        ],

        "spaced-comment": ["error", "always", {
            "line": {
                "markers": ["/"],
                "exceptions": ["-", "+"]
            },
            "block": {
                "markers": ["!"],
                "exceptions": ["*", "+", "-"],
                "balanced": true
            }
        }],

        "space-in-parens": ["error", "always", {
            "exceptions": ["()", "empty", "{}", "[]"]
        }],

        "object-curly-spacing": ["error", "always", { "arraysInObjects": false }], 

        "no-trailing-spaces": ["error", { "ignoreComments": true }]
    }
}
}
```

I tried to amend the rules even adding the @babel prefix but to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get around this using this config ( mainly removed the sourceType from the equation)

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true,
        "mocha": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:import/errors",
        "plugin:import/warnings"
    ],
    
    "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",

    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        // "sourceType": "module",
        "requireConfigFile": false,
        "babelOptions": {
          "plugins": [
            "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-assertions"
          ]
        }
    },
    
    "rules": {
        
        "indent": ["error", 4],

        "linebreak-style": ["error", "windows"],

        "quotes": ["error", "single"],

        "semi": ["error", "always"],

        "prefer-template": ["error"], 

        "block-spacing": ["error", 
            "always"
        ],
        
        "spaced-comment": ["error", "always", {
            "line": {
                "markers": ["/"],
                "exceptions": ["-", "+"]
            },
            "block": {
                "markers": ["!"],
                "exceptions": ["*", "+", "-"],
                "balanced": true
            }
        }],

        "space-in-parens": ["error", "always", {
            "exceptions": ["()", "empty", "{}", "[]"]
        }],

        "object-curly-spacing": ["error", "always", { "arraysInObjects": false }], 

        "no-trailing-spaces": ["error", { "ignoreComments": true }],

        "no-var": "error",

        "prefer-const":"error"
    }
}
```